# setInterval keeps giving me undefined function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function in my code which works as a slider for elements within a class.
I want to `setInterval` to it on click event but keeps giving me function is undefined.

Here is my Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slide").click(
        setInterval( function fadeNext() {
            $(this).children('div:nth(0)').children('img:nth(0)').fadeOut().appendTo($(this).children("div:nth(1)"));
            $(this).children("div:nth(1)").children('img:nth(0)').fadeIn().appendTo($(this).children("div:nth(0)"));
        },1000)
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the setInterval functions `this` belongs to the anonymous function, not the click one. So you need to pass `this` in the interval.
Solution is to use bind on the anonymous function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".slide").click(function(){
    setInterval(function fadeNext() {
        $(this).children('div:nth(0)').children('img:nth(0)').fadeOut().appendTo($(this).children("div:nth(1)"));
        $(this).children("div:nth(1)").children('img:nth(0)').fadeIn().appendTo($(this).children("div:nth(0)"));
    }.bind(this), 1000)
)
});
});
```

Or just

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".slide").click(function(){
var _this = this;
    setInterval(function fadeNext() {
        $(_this).children('div:nth(0)').children('img:nth(0)').fadeOut().appendTo($(this).children("div:nth(1)"));
        $(_this).children("div:nth(1)").children('img:nth(0)').fadeIn().appendTo($(this).children("div:nth(0)"));
    }, 1000)
)
});
});
```

Comment: @Satpal No, I wanted to show a solution without bind, but I copied the code in the above example. Notice that I used $(_this)

Comment: click is expecting a `function`, you havent wrapped your code in a `function`

Comment: Well I just wanted to show a solution to the problem, which is working. I copied the authors code, so it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

May be try something with jQuery delay and fadeOut callback. I havent tested this myself.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slide").click(function () {
            $(this)
                .children('div:nth(0)')
                    .children('img:nth(0)')
                    .delay(1000);
                    .fadeOut(400, function(){
                        $(this).appendTo($(this).children("div:nth(1)"));
                    });
    });
});
```